# ldap for django cannot be installed

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I have a question, is django-auth-ldap available for python 3.4? ldap package seems to be available but this other one either I cannot install or is not available yet. A hack anyone?

Comment: how do you install it?

Comment: pip3.4 install django-auth-ldap

Comment: Pypi seems to have the lib. Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: File "setup.py", line 53
    print name + ': ' + cfg.get('_ldap', name)
             ^
and then when I fix the mistakes because it is the print that requires brackets and some functools error, basic stuff between 2.6 and 3.3 I get 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not via pip install python-ldap.

As per https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/

> Support for Python >= 3.3 is considered experimental at this time.
>   Since python-ldap doesn’t support Python 3 yet, you have to install a
>   fork:
>
> ```
> $ pip install git+https://github.com/rbarrois/python-ldap.git@py3
> ```

This has been working fine for me on Python 3.4.